# How can I return variables from PHP server to iOS ? (use ASIHTTP)

Tags: php, iphone, ios, objective-c, asihttprequest

I had POST a file from iOS to server(use PHP) ,
and I want PHP server to return some variables to iOS,
I use

```
>[request responseString]
```

to get server response,

but it always return my HTML code(about the first page of my web)
and I want to return variables from the 3rd page of my web.

in another words,it means POST something back from PHP to iOS.

How can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably got something like

```
include('header.html');
```

in your PHP somewhere, loading up the html you're seeing in iOS. You need to make sure that the **ONLY** output of the script is the data you want to return to iOS, e.g.

```
<?php

... process data from iOS
echo $data_to_send_back_to_ios;
```

**ANY** output from the script, ANYWHERE, is going to show up in your client.

Note that you don't "post back" to ios. That'd mean your ios device is running a webserver. There's no need for a fullblown second http connection to return data... you've already got a connection to the server, over which you send the ios->php post data. Use that connection to return the response.

Answer (score 0):

There are different methods to achieve this, one of the most popular method is to use serialising your output in JSON format which makes it easy to parse on iOS. So what you need to do is use this in PHP

```
<?php

// Only PHP code you need to pass to iOS

echo json_encode($_POST);

?>
```

Now on iOS, first download this library and include it in your Xcode Project https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON then you need to do this to retrieve the $_POST variables after you get response

```
NSString *jsonString = [request responseString];
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *postVars = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsArray:jsonData error:&error];
```

and Now you have all your $_POST variables in *postVars array.

Comment: You means it's 
`$json_string = '{......}';`
`echo json_encode($json_string);`
but my client shows (null).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Tutorial that worked pretty well for me. Maybe it does for you to:

part1:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app

part2:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service